# PowerShell script to set SharePoint list to read only

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, office-365-developer

Can any one help on how to set the SharePoint online site List/Library to read only using Power-Shell script?

Answer (score 0):

There's no setting as such but you can give the List or Library unique permissions and set all groups/users to have only Read permissions to the list.

Here is an article that describes how to do this using PowerShell:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/09/make-sharepoint-list-library-read-only-using-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set-PnPListPermission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistpermission?view=sharepoint-ps) to remove and add users/groups permissions.

Two blogs for your reference:

[SharePoint Online: Remove User or Group from List Permissions using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-remove-user-group-from-list-permissions-using-powershell.html)

[SharePoint Online: Grant Permission to List or Library using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/05/sharepoint-online-grant-permission-to-list-library-using-powershell.html)